# Comparing first array in arrayList with rest of arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, oop, arraylist

I'm trying to make a scheduling talks where two can't proceed at the same time. After putting the first talk into Scheduler plan, I want to go through each talk in my arrayList and check if there compatible with the last talk in the schedule.

I figure I can compare by doing something along the lines of

```
public Scheduler getSchedule(){ //Scheduling attempt
        Scheduler plan = new Scheduler(events);
        this.events.add(events.get(0));

        for (int i=0; i < events.size(); i++)
        {
          if(events.get(i).getStartTime().compareTo(events.get(l).getendTime()) > 0);
          this.events.add(events.get(i));
        }

        return plan;
    }
```

Then in my Event class I have

```
 public int compareTo(Time that){               
    if(this.getHour() < that.getHour())
        return -1; 
    else if(this.getHour() > that.getHour())
        return 1;
    else if(this.getMinute() < that.getMinute())
        return -1;
    else if(this.getMinute() > that.getMinute())
        return 1;
    else
    return 0;

}
```

The problems I'm getting are `The method getHour() is undefined for the type Event`

Comment: Where is the getHour() method?

Comment: Okay I am gonna ask it. do you have a `getHour()` method in the Event class?

Comment: Then: *that* is of type *Time* not Event. So that part would not work either.

Comment: I have `private int getMinute() {
  return 0;
 }

 private int getHour() {
  return 0;
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Since getHour() is private you cannot use it outside class like that.getHour() (in your code). Change access modifer from private to public(just a suggestion)